# How did the server avoid "address already in use error" after the first or second message sending (java multithreaded socket programming)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a text messaging program with three files (main function file, client file, server file)

If "-l" is present on the command line, it will run as a server, otherwise it will run as a client

Command line arguments to run server:

```
java DirectMessengerCombined -l 3000
```

Command line arguments to run client:

```
java DirectMessengerCombined 3000
```

Text of error:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
at DirectMessengerServer.run(DirectMessengerServer.java:41)
at DirectMessengerServer.runSend(DirectMessengerServer.java:111)
at DirectMessengerServer.run(DirectMessengerServer.java:58)
at DirectMessengerServer.<init>(DirectMessengerServer.java:16)
at DirectMessengerCombined.main(DirectMessengerCombined.java:21)
```

Screenshot of error (server on left, client on right):

[image: server is left window, client is right window]

The problem with the screenshot is that the left window (server) was able to send and recieve text messages to the client until the server sends the "hello" message.

Code of main Server file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
public class DirectMessengerServer
{

    private String[] serverArgs; // <-- added variable
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;

    public DirectMessengerServer(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable
        this.serverArgs = args;
        run();
    }

      public String[] ServerRun(String[] args) throws IOException 
      {
          //How do I get the String[] args in this method be able to access it in the run methods?
        serverArgs = args;
        serverArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);

        return serverArgs;

      }




Thread ListeningLoop = new Thread();    
//run method of ServerRecieve
public void run() throws IOException
{  


    try
    {
        int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(serverArgs[1]);
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
        socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
        while(keepRunning)
        {

            //Reading the message from the client



            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client: "+ MessageFromClient);

           // ServerSend.start();

            runSend();



        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

Thread ServerSend = new Thread ();

//Run method of ServerSend
public void runSend()
{   
    while(keepRunning)
    {
        System.out.println("Server sending thread is now running");
        try
        {         

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            //creating message to send from standard input
            String newmessage = "";
            try 
            {
                // input the message from standard input
                BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String line = "";

                line= input.readLine(); 
                    newmessage += line + " ";

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            }
            String sendMessage = newmessage;
            bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+sendMessage);
            run();
        }


        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}


}
```

Code of Client file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerClient
{
    private String[] clientArgs; // <-- added variable
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public DirectMessengerClient(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable
        this.clientArgs = args;
        run(args);


    }
    public String[] ClientRun(String[] args)
    {
        clientArgs = args;
        clientArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
        return clientArgs;
    }

    Thread ClientSend = new Thread();   
    public void run(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        System.out.println("Client send thread is now running");
        while(keepRunning)
        {             
             String port_number1= args[0];
             System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
             int port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
             String host = "localhost";
             InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
             socket = new Socket(address, port);


             //Send the message to the server
             OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
             OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

             //creating message to send from standard input
             String newmessage = "";
             try 
             {
                 // input the message from standard input
                 BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                 String line = "";

                 line= input.readLine(); 
                 newmessage += line + " ";


              }
              catch ( Exception e )
              {
                     System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
              }
                String sendMessage = newmessage;
                bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                runClientRead(args);
            }

        }


    Thread ClientRead = new Thread();
    public void runClientRead(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        System.out.println("Client recieve/read thread is now running");

            //Integer port= Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
            //String host = "localhost";
            //InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            //socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromServer = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from server: " + MessageFromServer);

    }
}
```

Code of main function file:

```
  import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectMessengerCombined
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        DirectMessengerClient client1 = null;
        DirectMessengerServer server1 = null;

          for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {

              if (args.length == 1) 
              {
                 client1  = new DirectMessengerClient(args);
                 client1.ClientRun(args);
              }
              else if (args.length == 2)
              {
                 server1 = new DirectMessengerServer(args);
                 server1.ServerRun(args);
              }
           i=args.length + 20;
          } 
    }

}
```

My question is not only how to resolve the error (there's plenty of other questions that covered this) but why wasn't the error triggered the first time the messages were sent/received to/from the server?

Comment: In your DirectMessengerServer, runClientRead method you are calling run method the second time. This causes the exception as the port is already in use due to your first call. A better solution would be to have some sort of init method to initialize the connection on both server and client which gets invoked only once.

Comment: @Libin  see. The server's connect method would have socket.accept() but for the client it seems like I only need the port number. Is this true?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking me.